# Library not found for -llib. (clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation))

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, linker-errors

I am working on a project that was previously done and uploaded on app store.When I run this app in Xcode 5.0 it is working fine but when I run this on Xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008) I am getting Linker error on both device and simulator.

Error Message- **Library not found for -llib. (clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation))**.

I have searched a lot but I didn't get any thread about `Library not found for -llib` error. Is there anything I have to change in build settings to resolve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the linker command line in detail for the `-L` options being used:

[image]

Then use *Terminal* or *Finder* to see if your `libXXX.a` file exists in those directories.  If the library exists elsewhere then you need to configure your *Library Search Paths*:

[image]

However there several details which you have not provided in your question when using a library within an app:

- Is the library built as part of the Xcode project/workspace (as in the first image)?
- Is the library supplied by a third-party with binary (`.a`) and header files (as in the second image)?

Comment: Thanks! Was stuck on a similar iOS library link error, it helped. :)

Comment: it's now 2016 and this topic frees me out from all the headache! Should mark this as an answer

Comment: @trojanfoe All the libraries were generated by Xcode and none of them was supplied by a third party (.a) . Can you suggest solution for this scenario. I have same error using latest reat native and xcode

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: I ran `make` in the wrong directory so the paths were messed up.

Problem:

```
>make
linking ../build/release/yubikey-personalization-gui
/usr/x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -llib
...
```

I ran into this when compiling the Yubikey Personalisation Tool. I tracked down the `-llib` call in my `Makefile` which looked like this:

```
...
LINK = @echo linking $@ && g++
...
LIBS = $(SUBLIBS)  -L/usr/lib64 -L../lib/release -llib -lyubikey -lykpers-1 -lQtGui -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtCore -lpthread 
...
$(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJCOMP) $(LIBS)
```

So it was setting a variable called `LINK` which would print "linking" and then call `g++`, which is the compiler.
Then it set the var `LIBS` which would hold the ominous `-llib`.
Then it composes and runs the command `$(LINK) ... $(LIBS)`.
Which runs `g++` with the parameter `-llib`.

And what does that do? Turns out `-l<something>` is telling the compiler to use the `something`-library. So it asks for the library called `lib` here. Which is strangely generic. I figured out that the sources came with a directory called `lib/`, which was at `../lib`.

So starting `make` from a directory higher up fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

You should remove libstdc++ from other linker flags in your xcode project

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53103383/1344237