# Xcode 10 Beta 5 — clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, linker-errors, xcode10

Can anybody help me out? Everything worked fine on my project but after updating to Xcode10 Beta5 I'm getting this error when trying to run the App on my iPhone. Simulator however works… Please Help me!!!

[image]

I already did a web search on this problem and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290207/pods-issue-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1) thread. I tried all answers but none worked..

If you had this problem I would be very very thankful if you can help me running my app on my iPhone again

These are the pods I've integrated: 
[image]

and this is my pod file:
[image]

Comment: Please look in the build log to see what further information is available.

Comment: It says: ld: 154 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64. And in the log there are several duplicate symbols for both Crashlytics and Fabric.. How can I get rid of them?

Comment: The error says to pass `-v` to see the invocation. My guess is that Crashlytics and Fabric are being passed to the linker multiple times, causing the duplicate symbol errors.

Comment: and where do I pass the -v ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51602785/3151675 (still waiting for an answer, but the linked question gained more traction)

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741999/crashlytics-doesnt-work-with-xcode-10-beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. It turned out that something in Fabric and/or Crashlytics was wrong. Since it's not essential for the app I tried to remove both pods and voila it builds and runs.

Answer (score 23):

"libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd" is deprecated in iOS 12. 
In order to solve this, try to go to your

> App Targets - General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries -> Find `libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd` and delete it.

Then I added "libc++.tbd" and now you will be able to compile your project. Hope It helps.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Pods folder in the Project :

Pods/Pods-[Project].xcconfig

and remove the libaray

[image]

Comment: This in combination with the Other linker flags, was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Finding `-l"stdc++.6.0.9"` in the "Other Linker Flags" and removing it and adding `libc++.1.tbd` in the "Link Binary With Libraries" fixed this for me